# Как вставить разрыв строки в комментaриях?

Tags: поддержка

В [справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) описано два способа:

> Закончите строку 2 пробелами или добавьте разрыв строки <br/>

Но у меня оба способа почему-то в комментариях не работают. Тег **<br/>** в обоих вариантах (**<br/>** и **<br>**) выводится в неизменном виде и не обрабатывается. А два пробела просто игнорируются.
Подскажите, как правильно вставить разрыв строки в комментарий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Увы, в комментариях невозможно вставить разрыв.

Comment: Жаль... Но спасибо за ответ!